# Better way of handling keys

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I have three tables like this:

```
 public class Guides
 {
     public int Id { get; set; }

     [Required]
     public List<Ingredients>? Ingredients { get; set; } = new List<Ingredients>();
     public string? WritenGuide { get; set; }
}

public class Ingredients
{
    [Key]
    [Required]
    [MaxLength(50)]
    public string? Name { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [MaxLength(50)]
    public float Volume { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(50)]
    public float TotalCalories { get; set; }
}

public class IngredientTabs
{
    [Key]
    [Required]
    [MaxLength(50)]
    public string? Name { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [MaxLength(50)]
    public int Kcal { get; set; }
}
```

Every guide has list of ingredients, every ingredient has name as key, volume, and total calories which is volume * Kcal. I want to connect Ingredients and IngredientTabs but for some reason EF does not let me do that. When I try to put data into the database from json file like this:

```
[
  {
    "Id": 1,
    "Ingredients": [
      {
        "Name": "onion",
        "Volume": 1
      },
      {
        "Name": "chicken",
        "Volume": 900
      },
      {
        "Name": "ginger",
        "Volume": 10
      },
      {
        "Name": "garlic",
        "Volume": 10
      },
    "WritenGuide": "Bla bla bla"
  }
]
```

I get an error message telling me I have two instances with same key value

[error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BFVnW.png)

I could solve this problem by putting Id in both Ingredient and IngredientTab as Key, but it seems weird that I would have to have extra column that I won't use.

I was looking for an answer, but so far I haven't figured out what am I doing wrong. I will be very glad for any advice.

Comment: *"EF does not let me do that"*. What does that mean? What EXACTLY are you doing and what EXACTLY is happening?

Comment: *"extra column that I won't use"*. But you will use it... as the key. Surrogate keys are very, VERY common. In my office, we use surrogate keys for EVERYTHING. Every table/entity has a column/property specifically for a key that has no meaning at all to the application domain and exists specifically to provide a unique identifier. If nothing else, numeric keys are more efficient than text, so you can get better performance when joining or searching. The difference may not be noticeable unless the volume of queries is large.

Comment: Using surrogate keys also allows for the modification of data without modifying keys. For instance, you might want to change the name of an ingredient at some point, which would currently require you to change a key value. That's not the end of the world but it's generally best avoided if possible.

Comment: I have edited the post to include error message I'm getting. Any way thank you for the explanation on why the surrogate key is better to include in table, I was just thinking since I am always going to join and search for the ingredient through name, because it is more natural for me, I can just use it as key as well

Comment: primary key is mandatory on most ORM. it helps them to identify which is which. it would best to have surrogate key should the rows dont have natural key. also, you can choose integer as surrogate key, they are cheaper storage-wise.